# Pentaho Kettle update salesforce

Tags: data-loader, import

I get the following error when trying to update salesforce from a CSV

> Errors were found on item 0 Error code is: INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD Error message: Office: value not of required type: core.filemanager.ByteBlobValue@51ca5228

Kettle version is 7.0.0.0-25

[image]

CSV Input Fields
[image]

Mapping to salesforce (the latest step)
[image]

As I understand there is something connected to the encoding of value from a CSV, but have no idea how to fix it. (When I import from a CVS set to UTF-8 encoding)

Comment: Can you share fields section for Update and import for csv steps? I have seen something similar due to type mismatch earlier

Comment: @kurunve, added screenshots of fields sections of CSV input and salesforce output

Comment: which type is Office__c field?

Comment: @kurunve On salesforce this is a Text Field (length: 255)